Why did the startouch elves not act against Aaravos?
The startouch elves take a very dim view of teaching humans magic against what they consider the cosmic order, to the extent that

 they killed Leola—permanently, as far as we can see—for transgressing this law.

However, Aaravos did the same thing on a much broader scale by teaching humans dark magic. Not only that: by

 helping Claudia craft a moon primal stone,

he committed the exact same crime for which Leola had been judged.
Furthermore, Aaravos framed his actions in the seventh season as an intentional crime against the notion of order that the other startouch elves had, so one might expect this to also incur their wrath to an even greater degree.
However, the startouch elves never seem to have taken the opportunity to execute Aaravos or even judge him for his crimes, with the archdragons seemingly having imprisoned him initially.
Why is this?
